# Python - making a dict from an ordered list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am trying to make a `dict` ordered by the value of the keys.

I start with this:

```
a = [0, 4, 8, 16]
b = [0.15, 0.50, 0.33, 0.009]
d = {}
d.update(zip(a, b))
#{0: 0.15, 8: 0.33, 4: 0.5, 16: 0.009}
```

i.e. the `dict` is scrambled *even though the keys in the list were ordered*.

So, based on suggestions found on other questions here, I try `sorted`:

```
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
#[(0, 0.15), (4, 0.5), (8, 0.33), (16, 0.009)]
```

which gives me my desired set of ordered tuples.

Then I go back to a `dict`:

```
fin = dict(d)
#{0: 0.15, 8: 0.33, 4: 0.5, 16: 0.009}
```

but the order is scrambled again!

So:

- Why do dicts scramble the order of the keys, i.e. why do they not preserve the order of list of keys that I defined?
- *Can* I make an ordered dict as I would like? I.e. `{0: 0.15, 4: 0.5, 8: 0.33, 16: 0.009}`?

Comment: Because dictionaries (before Python 3.7) are not ordered. There is no reason to rely on the ordering of keys.

Comment: If you try to keep a dict ordered, you're gonna have a bad time

Comment: Don't think closing it as a dup was a great thing, there were two parts of the question, how to get oredering in the dict everyone is answering but its clear the OP also wanted to understand why the values in dict are not oredered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DanielRoseman  says, dictionaries have no order (until Python 3.7 where this is part of the language implementation).

If you need it to be ordered, use `collections.OrderedDict`. It functions pretty much like a regular dictionary:

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict(zip(a, b))
```

Comment: I'd also add, if you really need your dict to be ordered for your code to work, you may want to rethink your code.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Just that if you're relying on your dict being in a specific order, there's probably a better/more pythonic way to do whatever you're doing.

Comment: @SuperStew I think that's a bit sweeping. Why would they bother to go to the effort of implementing it as a guarantee in the standard library if it's an antipattern? I suspect the motivation was the same as for JSON Lines. In my last company, we used it to feed dictionaries of information into a simulation in a fixed order, now we could have just used a regular dict.

Comment: @SuperStew I agree, but I'm not the OP here :) Just providing an answer that works. I'm not in my place to recommend an alternative implementation other than `dicts` without further context from the OP.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes you may be right, I suppose for some specialized cases an ordered dict would be required.